# Sign-extend a number in C

Tags: c

I am having trouble trying to sign-extend a number by extracting part of a bit-string. This has trouble when it is a negative number, it wraps the number around to the positive side.
Here is my code:

```
//  printf("add1 \n");
unsigned short r1 = (instruction>>6)&7;
signed short amount = (instruction& 31);   //right here! i am trying to get the last 5 bits and store it in a register but i can't figure out how to make it negative if it is negative
//  printf("\namount is %d \n", amount);
unsigned short dest = (instruction>>9)&7;
state->regs[dest] = state->regs[r1]+amount;
setCC(state,state->regs[r1]+amount);
```

Comment: `instruction & 31` is not going to be negative. Try `instruction << 27) >> 27` (if it is a 32-bit signed integer).

Comment: @n.m.: `instruction << 27) >> 27` has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For bit patterns, it's often easier to use hex constants instead of decimal.

```
signed short amount = (instruction & 0x1F);
```

Then to sign-extend the number, check the sign-bit (assuming the *sign-bit* here is the left-most of the 5 extracted bits). <del>If it's set, do a binary inversion and add 1.</del> Take the 2's-complement of the 5-bit value (invert and add one), then take the 2's-complement of the full-width result (invert and add 1).

```
if (amount & 0x10)
    amount = ~(amount^0x1F + 1) + 1;
```

Eg.

```
             5-bit "bitfield"
             X XXXX
0000 0000 0001 1111
0000 0000 0000 0000 invert x ^ 0x1F (= 1 1111)
0000 0000 0000 0001 add 1
1111 1111 1111 1110 invert ~
1111 1111 1111 1111 add 1

0000 0000 0001 0000
0000 0000 0000 1111 invert x ^ 0x1F (= 1 1111)
0000 0000 0001 0000 add 1
1111 1111 1110 1111 invert ~
1111 1111 1111 0000 add 1
```

Ooops. Even simpler:

```
-(x^0x1F + 1)  Assuming the machine operates with 2's-complement

0000 0000 0001 0110
0000 0000 0000 1001 invert
0000 0000 0000 1010 add 1 (yielding the full-width absolute value)
1111 1111 1111 0110 negate
```

Comment: It's a `short`, not a `char`... shouldn't that be `0x1000`?

Comment: The value extracted in only 5 bits wide. The sign bit has to be one of those 5.

Comment: @KScottPiel, `(instruction & 0x1F)` is a 5-bit value. I suspect as well that this is what OP wants to extend.

Comment: True... but the sign bit for `instruction` is the left-most bit, regardless of what bits he's looking at on the right end of the number. Yes? Otherwise, you're depending on the 5th bit being 1 when `instruction` is negative which it may or may not be depending on the value of `instruction`

Comment: That's the sign-bit of the *type*, not necessarily of the *data*. But, I'll edit to add the assumptions I'm making.

Comment: I'll buy that... +1 on that basis.

Comment: Thanks, @KScottPiel. That's my mortarboard. See y'all tomorrow!

Comment: The inversion of bits may not do the expected thing, for example it converts 63 to -63, while OP probably wanted to convert it to -1

Comment: -1: "invert and add 1" does not sign extend, it negates, which is completely wrong.  You need to copy the sign to all the upper bits, which is easiest to do by testing and doing an unsigned subtract -- `if (amount & 0x10) amount -= 0x20;`

Comment: I'd argue it was *half-* wrong. But simpler to fix it. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 3):

use bitfields:

```
union {
      int a;
      struct {
         int a:5;
         int b:3;
         unsigned int c:20;
      } b;
} u = 0xdeadbeef;

int b = u.b.b;  // should sign extend the 3-bit bitfield starting from bit 5
```

Answer (score 2):

From Hacker's Delight 2-6. Assuming 5 bits of data that must be sign extended (sign bit has value 16).

Best case: If the upper bits are all zeros:

```
(i ^ 16) - 16
```

Next best case (as with OP's `instruction`): If the upper bits contain data that must be discarded:

```
(i & 15) - (i & 16)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can sign extend a 5-bit two's complement value portably without tests:

```
int amount = (instruction & 31) - ((instruction & 16) << 1);
```

More generally, it the field width is `n`, non zero and less than the number of bits in an `int`, you can write:

```
int amount = (instruction & ~(~1U << (n - 1) << 1)) -
             ((instruction & (1U << (n - 1)) << 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the sign-bit and fix-up the result accordingly:

```
int width_of_field = 5;
signed short amount = (instruction& 31);
if (amount & (1 << width_of_field >> 1)) // look at the sign bit
{
    amount -= 1 << width_of_field; // fix the result
}
```

Alternatively, use a left-shift followed by a right shift:

```
width_of_field = 5;
signed short amount = (instruction& 31);
// It is possible to omit the "& 31", because of the left shift below
amount <<= 16 - width_of_field;
amount >>= 16 - width_of_field;
```

Note: must use two statements to avoid effects of promotion to `int` (which presumably has 32 bits).

Comment: Note that right-shifting signed values gives you an undefined result.  It will generally work on a twos-complement machine (which most are), but might fail on some obscure machine.

Comment: `amount <<= 16 - width_of_field`has undefined behavior for 16 bit `signed short`