# What is the best way to sign extend a number in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, bit

I have a 10 bit *signed value*. It's actually a 10 bit color value that i want to convert to an `int`.

The 10 bits are to be interpreted as a signed value within a larger `int`, where the other bits are zero.

I can think of 3 ways, shown here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void p(int v)
{
    printf("\t%d", v);
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = -2; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        unsigned int u = i & 0x3ff;

        int v;

        // method 1: test the bit
        v = u;
        if (u & 0x200) v = v ^ -0x400;
        p(v);

        // method 2: shift
        v = u<<(sizeof(int)*8-10);
        v >>= (sizeof(int)*8-10);
        p(v);

        // method 3: use sign extend
        v = (signed char)(u >> 2);
        v <<= 2;
        v |= u;
        p(v);


        printf("\n");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

is there a better way? Often there is with this bit twiddling problems.

Thanks for any input.

### Update

Adding two more methods. The first suggested by @cruz-jean is bit fields, and the second suggested by gcc after compiling the bitfields.

```
      // method 4: bit fields
        struct { int v:10; } f;
        f.v = u;
        v = f.v;

        // method 5: sign extend short
        v = (signed short)(u << 6);
        v >>= 6;
```

Out of interest it appears MSVC compiles #4 into #2 and gcc compiles #4 into #5.

Method 5 looks good.

Comment: Do you mean `C` or `C++`? I doubt the question should have both tags.

Comment: If you have a 10 bit signed value and you wanna convert it to an int you only need to cast, nothing else. Sign extension only means increasing the number of bits while retaining value and sign so..

Comment: If this value is part of structure bit field, you may simplify it quite a bit by simply declaring it as signed bit field - C/C++ will do all conversions automatically.

Comment: @Fredrik I meant that the 10 bits are to be interpreted as signed not that it fills the whole word. Sorry if unclear.

Comment: 10 bit signed value is already an int. What is troubling you? Or do you mean that you have 10-bit encoding of a number? Than what encoding are you using?

Comment: @FredLarson It's true my test program wont compile as C,  but the idea is valid for both.

Comment: `v = (u & 0x200) ? u - 0x400 : u;`

Comment: @SergeyA I added some clarification to the question. thanks.

Comment: What's your criteria for "better"?  Fastest?  Least code? 
 Easiest to read?  Easiest to write?  Most portable?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy You missed "doesn't invoke implementation-defined behavior or undefined behavior". All of OP's solutions have one or the other.

Comment: @user3386109:  Those fall under "Most portable."

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Good point. I think i mean; order by (portable, fastest).

Comment: Actually I was first to suggest bit fields. But I don't really care

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sign extend a nine-bit number in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814072/sign-extend-a-nine-bit-number-in-c)

Comment: other duplicates: [Sign-extend a number in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16220983/995714), [Signed Extension from 24 bit to 32 bit in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42534749/995714), https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#FixedSignExtend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare a 10-bit signed bitfield helper type and access the value as an `int`:

```
struct signed_10_bit
{
    int val : 10;
};

int some_10_bit_num = 0x3ff;
int extended = signed_10_bit{ some_10_bit_num }.val;
```

Comment: to be C compatible. I changed this to:
        struct { int v:10; } f;
        f.v = u;
        v = f.v;

Comment: MSVC generates shifts as in method 2, but gcc shifts into 16 bits from 10 and sign extends there.

Comment: @jkjyuio That's kind of a good thing. Write what you mean and trust the compiler to do it efficiently. Optimizers are very smart nowadays.

Comment: Thanks. I added your suggestion. bitfields is probably the way.

Answer (score 3):

Another one to try:

```
v = u | (0 - (u&0x200));
```

good for cpus where shift is slow.

Comment: I like it! Method #1 was motivated by slow shifts, but i didnt like the test. This is better. Some old CPUs can only shift 1 at a time and need a shift loop, so this would be the best way there. Not sure what the bitfields would generate on those.